# How to hide side panels so that they don't overlay each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 side panels that overlay each other when I click on their corresponding buttons. How can I hide one when another opens?

This is the menu that triggers the panels:

```
    <div id="resources-menu-main">
    <ul>
    <li id="toc-main-button"><a href="#toc-beginning" onclick="showLeftPanel();"><img src="gfx/toc.png" width="50" alt="Table of Contents"></a></li>
    <li id="footnotes-main-button"><a href="#footnotes-section" onclick="showFootnotesPanel();"><img src="gfx/footnotes.png" width="50" alt="Footnotes"></a></li>
    <li id="references-main-button"><a href="#references-section" onclick="showReferencesPanel();"><img src="gfx/references.png" width="50" alt="References"></a></li>
    <li id="images-main-button"><a href="#images-section" onclick="showImagesPanel();"><img src="gfx/images.png" width="50" alt="Images"></a></li>
    <li id="information-main-button"><a href="#information-section" onclick="showInformationPanel();"><img src="gfx/info.png" width="50" alt="Information"></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

This is one of the side panels (it has another menu within to facilitate navigation):

```
    <div id="footnotes-section">
    <a href="#" onclick="showFootnotesPanel();" class="controller">&lt;</a>
    <hr id="line">
    <h3>Resources<br/><br/></h3>
    <div id="resources-menu-panel">
    <ul>
    <li id="footnotes-panel-button"><a href="#footnotes-section" onclick="showFootnotesPanel();"><img src="gfx/footnotes.png" width="50" alt="Footnotes"></a></li>
    <li id="references-panel-button"><a href="#references-section" onclick="showReferencesPanel();"><img src="gfx/references.png" width="50" alt="References"></a></li>
    <li id="images-panel-button"><a href="#images-section" onclick="showImagesPanel();"><img src="gfx/images.png" width="50" alt="Images"></a></li>
    <li id="information-panel-button"><a href="#information-section" onclick="showInformationPanel();"><img src="gfx/info.png" width="50" alt="Information"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <hr id="line">
   <details open>
   <summary><h4><img src="gfx/footnotes.png" width="50" alt="Footnotes"><br/>Footnotes</h4></summary>
   [content]
   <h4><a href="#resources-menu">&uarr; Volver</a></h4>
   </details>
   </div>
```

This is the js function of the corresponding side panel:

```
    function showFootnotesPanel() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("footnotes-section");
    if (elem.classList) {
    console.log("classList supported");
    elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
      elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
    } else {
      elem.className = classes + " show"; 
    }
    console.log(elem.className);
    }
    }
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: can you put this into jsfiddle and add some styling? that will make it easier to see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it does not seem to work, the website is quite complex. I did take a screenshot. Does that help at all? Otherwise, is it possible to upload or share files here? Thanks!

Comment: yes, a screenshot might be helpful

Comment: Done! I have uploaded an image of the opened panel when the buttons on the main menu are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm still not exactly sure what you want, but I broke it down to a basic layout to make it simpler. Here's the fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/wvoa69r5/1/

Basically you show the div you want and then hide the previously shown div like this:

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
  var left = $('#left-div1');
  var leftShow = $('.left-div.show');
  left.addClass('show');
  leftShow.removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Hi cocoa, thank you for your answer. Your solution would require to change my whole website, though. Is there any way to do the same with my javascript and without using jquery? I used this example to make my panels: http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2011/07/showing-hiding-panels-with-html-and-css/. I only made 4 panels instead of 1, and a menu and a side arrow to trigger the panel. Does that help to understand my example better?

Comment: I have been trying to implement the solution you proposed, but my problem is that the same script should open the side arrow, allow navigation from the panels and highlight sections within the panels, and when I change it this won't work... That is the reason I would like to keep the script, but just add something that will close a panel when you open another. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: sorry about that. jquery was just a shortcut. you should be able to achieve the same thing with javascript. i'm not sure i'll be able to help you anymore though. i've updated the fiddle with the html/css/js from that tutorial.  http://jsfiddle.net/wvoa69r5/3/

Comment: i'm still somewhat a beginner with javascript also

Comment: Don't worry! You have been very helpful already... I am looking at a combination of both codes. Thank you for taking the time!